# Using Username to create SQLite Tablename in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I wanna use username to create table in SQLite. but when username has dot(.) or starts with numbers, program is crashed because of SQLite error (such as username=araz.13

how can I fix this problem?
here is my code

```
void CreateProfileDB(String Username) {

    String TBLname = Username + "Tbl";
    String CreateTBL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBLname + " ("
            + ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + Book + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + Lesson + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Question + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + Answer + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + Accent + " TEXT, " + Option1 + " TEXT, "
            + Option2 + " TEXT, " + Option3 + " TEXT, "
            + Option4 + " TEXT, " + Option5 + " TEXT, "
            + TrueOption + " TEXT, " + EnglishSen1 + " TEXT, "
            + EnglishSen2 + " TEXT, " + EnglishSen3 + " TEXT, "
            + PersianSen1 + " TEXT, " + PersianSen2 + " TEXT, "
            + PersianSen3 + " TEXT, " + FirstShow + " TEXT, "
            + LastShow + " TEXT, " + NoOfShow + " INTEGER, "
            + StepNo + " INTEGER, " + TrueNo + " INTEGER, "
            + WrongNo + " INTEGER, " + NextShow + " TEXT);";

    SQLiteDatabase PDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    PDB.execSQL(CreateTBL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [quote](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) the table name.

But it would be a better idea to use a single table and add the user name as a column.

Comment: each user table have special data belongs to each user and I wanna insert user history to the user table, so I can not use only one table for all users